# TYPO3 realurl utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I have a problem with tracking paramaters utm_source,  utm_medium and utm_campaign. I read the issue https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/300 and installed the 2.1.5 of realurl. It now works for me only if pageNotFoundOnCHashError is turned off in the install tool and I'm logged in the backend.

Did I forgot something maybe? Which is the correct configuration for utm_* params?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear all real URL tabels and add the params again to [FE][cHashExcludedParameters] works for me.